# Why does Socket.io establish a connection multiple times every second in Cordova projects?

Tags: javascript, cordova, socket.io

I have a Cordova app which I am currently developing for Android and IOS but testing on android.

The socket server will eventually be hosted on AWS but for now I am running a local server to develop and test.

I am using the browser platform to test this as I saw it had the same issues.

The issue I have is that when I open my Cordova app the socket
`socket.on('connect` function is called multiple times every second.

The same code layout in a non Cordova project doesn't seem to cause the same issues.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the server code:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('socket connected');        
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log('socket disconnected');
    });            
});

http.listen(3000);
```

And here is the client side code

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady () {
  var socket = io("http://localhost:3000");
  socket.on('connect', function() {
    alert("Never gets here");        
  });
}
```

Server log:

[image: Server log]

The browser log:

[image]

Comment: There are multiple threads regarding the same on SO and everywhere else on Internet, it is a common issue. Please go through a few.

Comment: Thank you - I did quite a bit of research before I posed this but I didn't understand what I should do to get my code working, or if it is even possible?

Answer (score 0):

It's because Client sends cyclic HTTP request or heartbeats to Server and after Server response the connection is closed.

Comment: Oh okay thank you, so is there not a way to keep the connection open? I'm confused, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Change this first of all at place of connect write connection.

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady () {
  var socket = io("http://localhost:3000");
  socket.on('connection', function() {
    alert("Never gets here");        
  });
}
```

If the problem is still there add a comment to this post.